# Shapefile vector point to ppp spatstat with polygon windows

Tags: r, polygon, point, spatstat

I always get error to this when converting shapefile point to ppp spatstat that windowed by a polygon shapefile

```
# polygon that to be window
neighborhoods <- st_read("neighborhoods/neighborhoods.shp")

# convert CRS to planar projection as recommended by (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597078/use-sf-polygon-object-as-window-in-spatstat)
neighborhoods_3857 <- st_transform(neighborhoods, crs = 3857)

# point that to be PPP spatstat
trees <- st_read("trees/trees.shp")

# convert to planar projection
trees_3857 <- st_transform(trees, crs = 3857)
```

The problems, the "trees_3857" doesn't have dataframe columns that represent in EPSG3857 coordinates, so Feature column of "trees_3857" doesn't have x and y columns that respect to EPSG 3857

```
q <- ppp(x=?, y=?, win=neighborhoods_3857)
```

what I have done but error

first =using as.ppp instead of ppp to convert a vector shp to ppp spatstat

```
test1 <- as.ppp(trees_3857, win=neighborhoods_3857)
Error in as.ppp.sf(trees_3857, win = neighborhoods_3857): unused argument (win = neighborhoods_3857)
```

second = add geometries of "trees_3857" to feature columns with QGIS named "xcoord" & "ycoord"

```
test2 <- ppp(trees_3857$xcoord, trees_3857$ycoord, win = neighborhoods_3857)
Warning message:
"65217 points were rejected as lying outside the specified window"
```

Comment: there are direct converters in sf https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1233  (Web Mercator, EPSG:3857, is not a good choice for a map projection - what is a good choice depends on where the data is, its extent, and what you are doing with it - but Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area and Lambert Conformal Conic are usually good places to start - some discuss here https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of something with `st_point` geometry using `st_coordinates`.

Make a simple points data set like you would get with `st_read` and `st_transform`:

```
> pts = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),A=letters[1:10]), coords=c("x","y"), crs=3857)
```

Then use `as.ppp` with the coordinates and the window:

```
> as.ppp(st_coordinates(pts),W=unit.square())
Planar point pattern: 10 points
window: rectangle = [0, 1] x [0, 1] units
```

I don't know why your `$xcoords` and `$ycoords` doesn't work, I can only suggest it or the window is in the wrong coordinate system, but hard to tell unless you show us some of it!

Comment: Can I upvote you for three thousand times? For first time, I know "st_coordinates" function. You solve my problem after I struggled for 18 hours.